# Reducing a list of points into a list of pairs of points

Tags: functional-programming, swift

I have some data…

```
let points = [(718, 620), (4596, 1280), (410, 333), (4597, 993), 
(410, 337), (4597, 996), (428, 337), (4597, 1000), (431, 335), (4599, 1044)]
```

… that follows the pattern

```
[(pointStartOne.x, pointStartOne.y), (pointEndOne.x, pointEndOne.y),
(pointStartTwo.x, pointStartTwo.x) // ...
```

I need to structure it to

```
typealias PointPair = [(start: Point, end: Point)]
struct Point {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}
```

Here is my code:

```
var result: PointPair = []
while i < points.count{
    result.append((Point(x: points[i].0, y: points[i].1), Point(x: points[i+1].0, y: points[i+1].1)))
    i+=2
}
```

I think maybe it is nice situation to use functional programming `reduce`

Here is code ituitive:

```
let result = zip((points.enumerated().filter({ (offset: Int, element: (Int, Int)) -> Bool in
        return offset%2==0
    })), (points.enumerated().filter({ (offset: Int, element: (Int, Int)) -> Bool in
        return offset%2==1
    }))).reduce(PointPair(), { (result: PointPair, arg) -> PointPair in
        let (one, other) = arg
        let (offset, point) = one
        let (offsetTwo, otherPoint) = other
        return result + [(Point(x: point.0,y: point.1), Point(x: otherPoint.0,y: otherPoint.1))]
    })
```

It is messy. Trying to use functional programming conveniently and elegantly.

Here is the improved code:

```
result = points.enumerated().reduce(into: PointPair(), {(temp, arg) in
        let (offset, point) = arg
        if offset % 2 == 0{
            temp += [(Point(x: point.0, y: point.1), Point(x: 0, y: 0) )]
        }
        else if let last = temp.last {
           temp[temp.count - 1] = (last.0, Point(x: point.0, y: point.1))
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the first version: A loop

```
var i = 0
while i < points.count {
    // ...
    i += 2
}
```

can be written as a for-loop over a *stride:*

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: points.count, by: 2) {
    // ...
}
```

which restricts the scope of `i` to the loop body, and makes it a constant. Now each loop iteration appends exactly one element to `var result: PointPair`, which means that we can write this as a `map` operation:

```
let result: PointPair = stride(from: 0, to: points.count, by: 2)
    .map { i in
        (start: Point(x: points[i].0, y: points[i].1),
         end: Point(x: points[i+1].0, y: points[i+1].1))
    }
```

This may already be the “functional” version that you are looking for, but let's also have a look at your other two variants.

The “intuitive code” creates two additional arrays by filtering the original one for even/odd indices. After filtering the arrays the offsets are not needed, giving the warnings

```
Immutable value 'offset' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
Immutable value 'offsetTwo' was never used; consider replacing with '_' or removing it
```

This can be fixed with

```
let (_, point) = one
let (_, otherPoint) = other
```

A better way is to use `compactMap()` (which can be thought of as a combination of `filter()` and `map()`) to create arrays of the points with even/odd indices, without the element offsets.

Using `reduce()` for creating the result array is inefficient, as it creates intermediate arrays for each iteration. `reduce(into:_:)` would be an improvement, but actually this is just a `map()`:

```
let result: PointPair = zip(
    points.enumerated().compactMap { (offset, element) -> Point? in
        offset % 2 == 0 ? Point(x: element.0, y: element.1) : nil },
    points.enumerated().compactMap { (offset, element) -> Point? in
        offset % 2 == 1 ? Point(x: element.0, y: element.1) : nil }
).map { ($0, $1) }
```

This looks a lot “less messy” than your original version, but still has the disadvantage of creating intermediate arrays.

I have not much to say about your last version. It uses `reduce(into:)` which is good to avoid the creation of intermediate arrays. The only disadvantage is that temporary pairs are created and modified in every second step.

So the  “stride + map” variant looks like the best to me: It is efficient and easy to read.

A final remark: The type alias

```
typealias PointPair = [(start: Point, end: Point)]
```

is misleading, because it does not define a pair of points but an *array* of pairs of points. I would probably define a dedicated type for a pair of points instead

```
struct Line {
    let from: Point
    let to: Point
}
```

and then use `[Line]`  as the result type.

Answer (score 2):

one other idea is to add `chunked` to `Array` (source: [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks)):

```swift
import UIKit

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}

struct Point {
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}


struct Line {
    let from: Point
    let to: Point
}
```

just for better prints in Playground -> it removes the `__lldb_expr` prefix:

```swift
extension Point: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "Point( x:\(x), y:\(y) )" }
}
extension Line: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String { return "Line( \(from) -> \(to) )" }
}
```

test it:

```swift
let points = [(718, 620), (4596, 1280), (410, 333), (4597, 993),
(410, 337), (4597, 996), (428, 337), (4597, 1000), (431, 335), (4599, 1044)]

let lines = points.map{ point in Point(x: point.0, y: point.1) }
                  .chunked(into: 2)
                  .map{ pointpair in Line(from: pointpair[0],to:pointpair[1]) }

dump(lines)
```

output:

```
▿ 5 elements
  ▿ Line( Point( x:718, y:620 ) -> Point( x:4596, y:1280 ) )
    ▿ from: Point( x:718, y:620 )
      - x: 718
      - y: 620
    ▿ to: Point( x:4596, y:1280 )
      - x: 4596
      - y: 1280
  ▿ Line( Point( x:410, y:333 ) -> Point( x:4597, y:993 ) )
    ▿ from: Point( x:410, y:333 )
      - x: 410
      - y: 333
    ▿ to: Point( x:4597, y:993 )
      - x: 4597
      - y: 993
  ▿ Line( Point( x:410, y:337 ) -> Point( x:4597, y:996 ) )
    ▿ from: Point( x:410, y:337 )
      - x: 410
      - y: 337
    ▿ to: Point( x:4597, y:996 )
      - x: 4597
      - y: 996
  ▿ Line( Point( x:428, y:337 ) -> Point( x:4597, y:1000 ) )
    ▿ from: Point( x:428, y:337 )
      - x: 428
      - y: 337
    ▿ to: Point( x:4597, y:1000 )
      - x: 4597
      - y: 1000
  ▿ Line( Point( x:431, y:335 ) -> Point( x:4599, y:1044 ) )
    ▿ from: Point( x:431, y:335 )
      - x: 431
      - y: 335
    ▿ to: Point( x:4599, y:1044 )
      - x: 4599
      - y: 1044
```